Does $x(t) = a \sin^2(\omega t+c)$ represent a Simple Harmonic Motion or not?
I had a doubt about the equation
$$x(t) = a \sin^2(\omega t+c).$$
Does this equation represent a Simple Harmonic Motion or not?
I did try it myself with 2 methods:

using trigonometry
using the general differential equation.

Both the results contradicted each other.
So what's the problem here?
$$x(t) = a\sin^2(\omega t + \phi)$$
$$\sin^2\theta = \frac{1-\cos2\theta}{2}$$
$$\implies x(t) = a\left(\frac{1-\cos\left(2\omega t + 2\phi\right)}{2}\right)$$
$$=\frac{a}{2}-\frac{a}{2}\cos(\omega't+C)\tag{shifted SHM}$$
General Diff. EQ$^n$
$$\rightarrow \ddot{x}(t) + \omega^2 x = 0$$
$x = a\sin^2\left(\omega t + \phi\right)$
$\ddot{x} = -a(2\omega^2)(\sin^2(\omega t + \phi)-\cos^2(\omega t + \phi))$
$$\rightarrow -a\omega^2(\sin^2(\omega t + \phi)) + a(2\omega^2)(\cos(\omega t + \phi))\tag{It should be zero.}$$

What definition of shm are you using?

I see a logical problem with this question. If I rely on the definition of SHM given in Wikipedia, it is a property of the differential equation and not of its solution. In other words, if your sine function comes out as a solution of an equation describing a harmonic oscillator, then yes, it describes SHM. However, exactly the same function can come out as a solution of some other nonlinear equation of motion (e.g. as some special limiting case), and then it is no longer SHM.

Therefore asking if a function itself is SHM is meaningless unless you specify from which equation of motion it was obtained. It is as meaningless as asking whether a quadradic function represents free fall. In fact, it can represent anything describable by a quadratic function, free fall in particular.

What you are calling shifted simple harmonic motion, I would call simple harmonic motion. The defining feature of simple harmonic motion is that the force acting on an object is proportional to that object's displacement from an equilibrium point. The differential equation you are using ($\ddot{x}+\omega^2x = 0$) assumes that the equilibrium position is $x = 0$. Moving the system to the side does not change the motion, just the coordinates we use to describe it. A more general equation for simple harmonic motion might be $\ddot{x} + \omega^2(x-p) = 0$, with equilibrium position $p$, but that doesn't look as nice.
A similar problem comes up when considering a mass on a vertical spring with gravity. In this case, the equation of motion is
$$\ddot{x} + \omega^2 x + g = 0.$$
This may not look like simple harmonic motion, until we make a change of coordinates.
$$\ddot{x} + \omega^2 x + g = 0$$
$$\ddot{x} + \omega^2 \left(x + \frac{g}{\omega^2}\right) = 0$$
$$y = x + \frac{g}{\omega^2}\qquad \ddot{y} = \ddot{x}$$
$$\ddot{y} + \omega^2 y = 0$$
So, the only effect of gravity on a vertical spring is to shift the equilibrium point. The motion is still simple harmonic.
The reason your second derivation (under the heading General Diff. EQ$^n$) didn't work is that $\omega$ isn't the angular frequency of the motion. The function $\sin^2(\omega t + \phi)$ oscillates at $2\omega$. You can see this in the identity $\sin^2(\theta) = \frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$. So, plugging $x(t)$ into the expression
$$\ddot{x} + 4\omega^2 x,$$
where $(2\omega)^2 = 4\omega^2$, will result in a constant.

“Shifted SHM” appears in handwriting in the image (which is one of the problems with images of handwritten equations).

Thankyou @Mark H


I had a doubt about the equation $$x(t) = a \sin^2(\omega t+c).$$ Does this equation represent a Simple Harmonic Motion or not?

Sure, by either method. I'll define new variables, $$\begin{align}x'(t) &= x(t) - \frac a 2\\ a' &= \frac a 2 \\ \omega' &= 2\omega \\ c' &= 2c\end{align}$$ With this, $$x'(t) 
= - a'\cos(\omega't + c')$$ and $$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(x'(t)) = a'{\omega'}^2 \cos(\omega't + c') = -{\omega'}^2x'(t)$$
This rewrite clearly obeys the differential equation for simple harmonic motion. Adding a constant to something that clearly is simple harmonic motion does not mean the result is not simple harmonic motion.

No, form of acceleration $a=m-nx$ is not a SHM, because doubling $x$ will not double acceleration $a$, unless you also will double constant $m$ (which you can't under the very definition of $F=-k x$). Hence OP given x(t) does not represent a simple harmonic motion.

@AgniusVasiliauskas What you wrote is wrong. Simple harmonic motion is defined as being sinusoidal about the mean. In other words, $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(x(t)-\bar x\right) + \omega^2\left(x(t)-\bar x\right) = \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(x(t)\right) + \omega^2\left(x(t)-\bar x\right) = 0$$ This simplifies a bit if the mean $\bar x$ is zero. If the mean is not zero the more general definition still applies.

No. You misinterpret definition of Simple Harmonic Oscilator. SHM by definition is when restoring force (or acceleration) is proportional to the displacement of oscillating body from equilibrium position. Here acceleration is in the form $a=x+k$ (more or less), right ? hence $a \not \propto x$, because by doubling $x$ from where you will start movement of body - you will not double body acceleration (unless $k \to 0$). So this denies Hooke law and so it's not SHM. (In other words your term $-a/2$ makes it an-harmonic). So you are wrong.

In other words SHM is not about being sinusoidal, but rather about acceleration responding proportionally to the displacement of body from equilibrium position. Which is not the case in OP system.

@AgniusVasiliauskas It is you, not me, who misunderstands SHM. It is the acceleration with respect to the mean position rather than the acceleration with respect to some other arbitrary point.  From the wikipedia article you cited, SHM " is a special type of periodic motion an object experiences by means of a restoring force whose magnitude is directly proportional to the distance of the object from an equilibrium position and acts towards the equilibrium position." Adding an arbitrary constant does not change this.

Exactly, and here acceleration is NOT proportional to the object distance from equilibrium position. Differentiate it with wolfram Alpha and you'll get it : $$ a =  2A ω^2 - 4 ω^2~x$$. Where do you see here acceleration proportionality to the displacement from equilibrium $x$ ? It's exactly NOT proportional to the displacement due to additional term $2A ω^2$ which needs to be added to the $x$. This destroys $a$ proportionality to the $x$ since by doubling $x$ you will not double $a$. Got it? So it's not SHM

In other words,- adding arbitrary constant to the $F=kx$ changes EVERYTHING, and namely destroys $F$ proportionality to the $x$. I'm sorry, but you really do not understand what it truly means to be "proportional".

@AgniusVasiliauskas Whatever. I am done with this conversation. Look at the other two answers, which clearly agree with my answer.

@AgniusVasiliauskas You are assuming that the equilibrium position is at $x=0$. In the OP, the equilibrium position is $x = a/2$. The force is proportional to the displacement from that position.

@MarkH Thanks, yes in this case I was wrong then.

$$ x = a\sin^2(\omega t + c) = \frac{a}{2}[1 - \cos[2(\omega t + c)]]$$
$$ \dot{x} = a\omega \sin[2(\omega t + c)]$$
$$\ddot{x} = 2a\omega^2 \cos[2(\omega t + c)] = -4\omega^2\left(x - a/2\right)  $$
But this is just of the form $\ddot{x} = -\alpha^2 (x-x_0)$, which is SHM with an equilibrium position at $x = x_0 = a/2$ and an angular frequency of $\alpha = 2\omega$.
